# DatabaseObjectNotClosedException even with try-with-resources

Tags: android

In my application, various components will connect try to fetch photo and music information from the android MediaStore.

I run into DatabaseObjectNotClosedExcepton like this:

```
? E/CursorLeakDetecter: PossibleCursorLeak:content://media/external/images/media,QueryCounter:6
? E/CursorLeakDetecter: android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
? E/CursorLeakDetecter:     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:491)
? E/CursorLeakDetecter:     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:405)
? E/CursorLeakDetecter:     at com.company.app.media.Photo.getAllPhotosInAlbumCursor(Photo.java:229)
? E/CursorLeakDetecter:     at com.company.app.media.Photo.getAllPhotosInAlbumCount(Photo.java:263)
? E/CursorLeakDetecter:     at com.company.app.view.PhotoAlbumSizeRetriever$1.run(PhotoAlbumSizeRetriever.java:89)
? E/CursorLeakDetecter:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
? E/CursorLeakDetecter:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
? E/CursorLeakDetecter:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:848)
```

Here is what the `getAllPhotosAlbumCount` function looks like:

```
public int getAllPhotoAlbumsCount(int flags) {
    try (Cursor f = getAllPhotoAlbumsCursor(flags)) {
        return f != null ? f.getCount() : 0;
    }
}
```

And `getAllPhotoAlbumsCursor`:

```
public Cursor getAllPhotoAlbumsCursor(int flags) {
    final CursorFields l = getAllPhotoAlbumsFields(flags);
    return context.getContentResolver().query(l.getUri(), 
        l.getProjection(), l.getSelection(), l.getSelectionArgs(), l.getSortOrder());
}
```

From my understanding, `Cursor` implements the `Closeable`, which should take care of the Cursor just fine.

I tried other versions of this (`try`, `catch`, `finally`), which also did not help.

Those functions are executed from various threads, including executors and background threads, and occasionally on the UI thread.

They are also called from `View`s within `RecyclerView` and `ViewPager` adapters.

What are the potential causes for this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, reading the Android source will help a lot.

`CursorLeakDetecter` is used in the class `ActivityThread`, here is the important bit:

```
// ...

if(uriMap.get(uri) == null) {
    uriMap.put(uri,1);
}else {
    uriMap.put(uri,uriMap.get(uri)+1);
}
// when uri>5, print log information
if(uriMap.get(uri) >= 5) {
    Log.e("CursorLeakDetecter", "PossibleCursorLeak:"+uri+",QueryCounter:"+uriMap.get(uri), stackTrace);
}

// ...
```

So the assumption is that a query, when requested 5 times, is a potential leak. Looking back at the method above, let's check how the list of photo albums is retrieved:

```
return new CursorFields(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, PHOTO_PROJECTION,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID + " = ? " + AND_PHOTO_FILTER, new String[]{Long.toString(albumId)},
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER + " ASC");
```

And as I mentioned, the function might be called multiple times from various threads, so it is definitely possible the *same* URI is called multiple times for *different* buckets.

A workaround is to append a query parameter:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    .buildUpon()
    .appendQueryParameter("bucket", Long.toString(albumId))
    .build()
```

That way, the query is different for each album, and no CursorLeak error message will be generated.